# Is it possible to prove 'implies_to_or -> de_morgan_not_and_not' without resorting to other classical laws?

Tags: coq

```
Theorem implies_to_or_to_de_morgan_not_and_not : 
  implies_to_or -> de_morgan_not_and_not.
Proof.
unfold implies_to_or, de_morgan_not_and_not, not.
intros.
Admitted.
```

```
1 subgoal
H : forall P Q : Prop, (P -> Q) -> (P -> False) \/ Q
P, Q : Prop
H0 : (P -> False) /\ (Q -> False) -> False
______________________________________(1/1)
P \/ Q
```

This is from the 5 star exercise near the end of SF Logic chapter.

I've bashed my head against this particular problem for too many hours now, so I really have to ask at this point. I've already proven `excluded_middle <-> peirce`, `peirce <-> double_negation_elimination`, `double_negation_elimination <-> de_morgan_not_and_not`, `implies_to_or <-> excluded_middle`, `de_morgan_not_and_not -> implies_to_or` so I already have more than all the paths covered. To me that only makes this problem that much more confusing and I do not understand why I can't even get this proof off the ground.

Somehow there just is not that much to work with here.

One option would be to do `exfalso` and try to do something from there, but that would throw away the `P \/ Q` goal and I suspect that would be too much of a loss of information even if I could make some kind of headway.

Another option would be to try and destruct `H`, but in that case there is a problem of trying to prove `P -> Q` without anything usable being in the premise.

I've had trouble with exercises in the past week and managed to surmount them with effort, but I am not experienced enough to just let this thing lie without asking for advice. What exactly am I not seeing here?

Obviously, I do not want to convert `de_morgan_not_and_not` to some other 
easier to solve classical law (like the excluded middle) as that would be besides the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Software Foundations book explicitly asks not to publish solutions, let me give a hint.

Notice that the hypothesis `H` is universally quantified wrt both propositions it talks about.
This means you can supply *any* propositions for `P` and `Q`, even *same* ones. Basically, this observation lets you reason classically, which is enough to solve this problem.

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I missed this. I actually did consider passing the same variable twice into the hypothesis, but that was before I could figure out how to destructure a function with foralls (with `assert`) and I forgot about it later.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you don't want to use your other proofs to prove this? It's fairly artificial to avoid using a result that you know is unconditionally true.

You can avoid manipulating `de_morgan_not_and_not` by using `implies_to_or` to perform case analysis on `P` and `Q` (refer to your proof of `implies_to_or -> excluded_middle`). Then you have four cases to look at, and all four resulting goals are simple 1-3 line proofs.

Comment: I should have seen the step I needed to do based on my proof of `implies_to_or -> excluded_middle`, but I tackled that one from a different angle and the fact that I am applying the same variable there to the hypothesis slipped by me. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Let me address your the part of your reply about avoiding using known results being artificial. It is true that for real work you'd want to do that. It would also make sense to just move on if one gets stuck rather than obsess over it. But Software Foundations is training. Whenever I make a mistake on these toy exercises and get stuck, it is due to a mental error. If I cannot debug those errors and overcome the obstacles, then I won't be able to do the much harder things afterwards. So it becomes a matter of pride to do this even if it kills me. I must do it this way.